# Trigger an event after clicking browse button in file upload field Extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am new in Extjs and I just had an issue with a fileuploadfield, basically what I want to do is to trigger an new event after clicking the browse button. I want to trigger both event. The one by default and the new event I am going to develop. Is there any way of doing that ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please show your latest non-working attempt at solving this problem. It is usually more instructive to see fixes to your code than to read someone else's solution. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

After render of the file upload field, you want to attach to the trigger component's click event like this:

```
listeners: {
    afterrender: function(field) {
        field.getTrigger('filebutton').component.on('click', function() {
            Ext.Msg.alert('Browse button clicked');
        });
    }
}
```

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2dn5

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I wanted. Thanks